# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)}\sin{((2n-1)x)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, summation

Evaluate

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)}\sin{((2n-1)x)}$$

for $x\in (0,\pi)$. I think it should be $(-2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}})^{-1}$, for all $x$. Can anyone show this?

I am trying partial summation as in the proof of the Dirichlet test, with no success so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)}\sin{((2n-1)x)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin{nx} - \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin{2nx}$$
and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin{nx} = \frac{\pi-x}{2}$$
for $x \in (0, \pi)$.

Comment: Great! Where might I find a proof of the sum you mention?

Comment: @EricAuld Fourier Theory.

Comment: Calculate the Fourier series of the function $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$\sin((2n-1)x) = \text{Imag}(e^{i(2n-1)x})$$
Hence, your sum is
$$T = \text{Imag}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{i(2n-1)x}}{2n-1}\right)$$
I trust you can finish it from here.

> Let $$S(a) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$ We then have $$S'(a) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{2n-2} = \dfrac1{1-a^2}$$ Hence, $$S(a) = \dfrac12 \log \left(\dfrac{1+a}{1-a}\right)$$ This gives us $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{i(2n-1)x}}{2n-1} = \dfrac12 \log \left(\dfrac{1+e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}\right) = \dfrac12 \log \left(i \cot\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)\right) = \dfrac12 \log \left(\cot \left(\dfrac{x}2\right)\right) + i \dfrac{\pi}4$$ Hence, $$T = \dfrac{\pi}4$$